# Retrieving json encrypted data

Tags: php, json

i got this json encoded data being sent to me.
can u tell me how to get each of the individual elements ?
Something like:

```
$ticket
$customer
$user


{"ticket":{"id":"10909446","number":"152"},"customer":{"id":"3909381","fname":"","lname":"","email":"me@site.com","emails":["me@site.com"]},"user":{"fname":"Test","lname":"Me","id":17396,"role":"admin"}}
```

this is a basic view on how my code runs.

```
            $ret = array('html' => '');
            $data = json_decode($data , true);

            $ret['html'] = '<ul><li>'.$data->ticket->number.'</li></ul>';

            echo json_encode($ret);
            exit;
```

it only prints the circle from the li tags.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php You should try looking up a way to do something before posting on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify @Cthulhu's answer :

```
$test = '{"ticket":{"id":"10909446","number":"152"},"customer":{"id":"3909381","fname":"","lname":"","email":"me@site.com","emails":["me@site.com"]},"user":{"fname":"Test","lname":"Me","id":17396,"role":"admin"}}';
$data = json_decode($test);
echo $data->ticket->id;
```

outputs

```
10909446
```

`json_decode` make the JSON into a `stdClass` object, and then you can access the values as that.

---

```
$data = json_decode($test);
$ret = array();
$ret['html']='<ul><li>'.$data->ticket->number.'</li></ul>';
```

return

```
json_encode($ret);
```

will return

```
{"html":"<ul><li>152<\/li><\/ul>"}
```

Comment: i tried it mate but it seems its not working. That code is sent from another webpage to my php file. i have to extract those values to perform other code updates and the json_encode what i want to send back to the initial webpage

    i tried something like
$data = json_decode($data);
//do stuff
echo json_encode($data->ticket->id);

just to see if the ticket id is sent back but its not

Comment: Your JSON may be invalid, so. The input JSON you have given here is OK. json_encode is to if you have created your result as an array - have you done that?

Comment: remember `json_encode($ret, true)` if you have deep nested array values

Answer (score 1):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is the answer for you.